# Can not push to Git server

Tags: git, push

I cloned a git project from repo and checkout normally, 
But when I try to push my code to master branch, It shows this error

fatal: Upload denied for project '------'

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities how to continue in this situation:

1) contact one of the project owners and request upload permissions for the project (access right 'Push')

2) export your commit as a patch using the git format-patch command and provide the patch file to one of the project owners